# 2019 - Close tab after php script executed (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, php

I found a lot of questions dealing with this, but most are from 2012 or before and there seems to be new security policies by Google, hence the question here in 2019.

My Chrome extension is opening up a new tab and navigates to a website with several PHP variables in tow. Once the site is opened, my PHP script does its magic, and once done, I would like to close the tab.

Now here's the problem:

1. Chrome Dev Kit throws an error saying "scripts may only close windows that it opened up"
2. My extension runs on JS and I dont think it can close tabs (or least I dont know how)
3. all the PHP side `echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.close();}, 5000);</script>';` solutions dont work because of the updated security policies

Now, how would one go about this?

Thanks,
A2k

Comment: Your #2 premise is likely false. If your extension opens a tab, it should be the only script able to close it, in the usual way. The only issue is getting the timing right; your serverside could emit a script at the end that uses `postMessage` to trigger your extension's tab-closing code.

Comment: I feel since you're wishing for a chrome extension to communicate cross domain, my "_postMessage_" solution may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to instruct the parent window to close the child window *by* the child window if you use `window.opener...` in the child or if you have a cross domain issue, use the `postMessage(...)` solution.

*Classic "window.opener reference" Solution:*

**parent.html**

```
<script>
  var childWindow = window.open("child.html","_blank");
</script>
```

**child.html**

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.opener.childWindow.close();
  },1000);
</script>
```

*Alternative "Post Message" Solution:*

*(Use this if you have a CORS Cross-Origin Resource Sharing issue.)*

**parent.html**

```
<script>
  window.open("child.html","_blank");
  window.addEventListener('message',function(e){
    if(e.data === 'CloseChildWindow')
      e.source.close();
  }, false);
</script>
```

**child.html**

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.opener.postMessage('CloseChildWindow','*');
  },1000);
</script>
```

Note that the setTimeout(); exists only to demonstrate this behavior, otherwise the window would close instantly. Also set the [appropriate domain parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) on postMessage() function.

Answer (score 1):

window.close() will only work if the window that you are trying to close() was opened by a script using window.open() method.

---

A workaround which might work for you if you are just looking to close the tab would be this

```
echo '<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        myWin = window.open("","_self")
        myWin.close();
    }, 5000);</script>'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sadly doesnt work. Chrome is picking up on it and throws the same error as before, preventing the closure. I guess I have to work on it from the the extension's side. thanks fro trying though.